# laravel php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

When I run `php artisan migrate`

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aviandb and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 68:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

In Connector.php line 68:

> PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

How can I solve?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your php mysql extension doesn't support the version of MySQL server you are running.

I'm assuming you're running MySQL 8.0, which is new at the time of this post.

You need to update or rebuild PHP with support for the latest version of MySQL, or downgrade your MySQL Server version.

Another solution is to create a user with the mysql_native_password option.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I've run into the same issue, so I followed your last suggestion to correct it. Indeed, I had to use the MySQL CLI in order to create the users with that option, because the latest version of MySQL Workbench as I'm typing this (8.0.11rc) doesn't let you do so. I can create with `Standard` selected as the `Authentication Type`, but as soon as I Apply those changes, it automatically changes to `caching_sha2_password` and is grayed-out so I cannot change it again. I even have `mysql_native_password` set as the `default_authentication_plugin` in the options file.

Comment: @Sturm, honestly, I wouldn't even touch MySQL 8.0 yet.  Not worth the trouble and possible instability unless you absolutely need one of the new features.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, @Devon. I actually didn't mean to do so; I just did a simple `brew update` and `brew upgrade`, not realizing it would wipe out my old MySQL installation, replacing it with the new 8.0 version.

Answer (score 12):

For

> PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

issue, there's a Japanese blog which covers this:

https://qiita.com/r641y/items/7f0ca12ced72363f9448

To summarize, you can log into mysql via command line then change the password type from `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password` type.

The code to achieve this within mysql is:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@"localhost" IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

You can replace 'user' and 'password' with your username and password to mysql.

Then within mysql again:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once that's done, remember to update the .env file's ()

> DB_USERNAME= and DB_PASSWORD= .

There's a sample video on how to get to .env file below:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/4?autoplay=true

Hope this helps!
It worked on my macbook pro high sierra.

Answer (score 5):

Run this script on your query mysql and just your new password it will be work

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password'
```

Answer (score 5):

**MySQL 8 & Laravel: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client**

So, here’s the fix. You can create a user with the “old” authentication mechanism, which the MySQL database driver for PHP still expects.

```
CREATE USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'user_name'@'localhost';

ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';
```

then restart `mysql` server

```
sudo service mysql restart;
```